# Redirect not working in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a link like this:

```
/add.php?id=50&link=page2
```

I want it to redirect to this:

```
/add/50/page2
```

How can I do this? I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
 Redirect /add.php?id=50&link=page2 /add/50/page2
```

Comment: I think it needs a third parameter: `Redirect /add.php?id=50&link=page2 /add/50/page2 -MakeItWork`

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /add\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)&link=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ add/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^add/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ add.php?id=$1&link=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: This is fully tested and working code on my Apache. Make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled. If it is enabled then check your Apache error.log for the reason of 500 error